# I need to know how to remove the target dependency selected

Tags: ios7, xcode5, itk

I have been trying to remove the target dependency selected with the remove icon but every time I try to remove it my Xcode closes! What should I have to do to remove it?

This is the report from Xcode:

```
Process:         Xcode [17289]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0.2 (3335.32)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3335032000000000~4
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 106632651
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [149]
Responsible:     Xcode [17289]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-01-16 19:34:26.831 -0600
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  B647B9AE-2882-33C7-31A3-43B507880929

Sleep/Wake UUID: 6FD8764A-5B71-406A-A40F-84268E86D23C

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A3005
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3575/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/PBXContainerItemProxy.m:260
Details:  Tried to access the containerPortal of an orphaned container item proxy. A common cause of this is corrupt project files which illegally reuse the same target dependency instance for multiple targets.
Object:   <PBXContainerItemProxy: 0x7fb205d2e9a0>
Method:   -_containerPortal
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fb203515100>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010e60bea8 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010d38f7a5 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010d38fad4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x00000001138f0f9c -[PBXContainerItemProxy _containerPortal] (in DevToolsCore)
  4  0x0000000113816694 -[PBXArchivingBinding writeValueForObject:toPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
  5  0x00000001138151ff -[PBXObject _archiveValuesForArchiveMask:toPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x0000000113815b96 -[PBXObject writeToPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x0000000113844d57 -[PBXPListArchiver _archiveObject:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
  8  0x0000000113847af8 -[PBXPListArchiver _encodeObject:forKey:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
  9  0x0000000113847e12 -[PBXPListArchiver encodeObject:forKey:] (in DevToolsCore)
 10  0x00000001138168e0 -[PBXArchivingBinding writeValueForObject:toPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 11  0x00000001138151ff -[PBXObject _archiveValuesForArchiveMask:toPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 12  0x0000000113815b96 -[PBXObject writeToPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 13  0x000000011388aa1a -[PBXTargetDependency writeToPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 14  0x0000000113844d57 -[PBXPListArchiver _archiveObject:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
 15  0x0000000113848093 -[PBXPListArchiver _createPListArrayForObjectArray:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
 16  0x000000011384880f -[PBXPListArchiver _encodeObjectArray:forKey:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
 17  0x0000000113848c0c -[PBXPListArchiver encodeObjectArray:forKey:] (in DevToolsCore)
 18  0x00000001138168e0 -[PBXArchivingBinding writeValueForObject:toPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 19  0x00000001138151ff -[PBXObject _archiveValuesForArchiveMask:toPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 20  0x0000000113815b96 -[PBXObject writeToPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 21  0x0000000113844d57 -[PBXPListArchiver _archiveObject:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
 22  0x0000000113848093 -[PBXPListArchiver _createPListArrayForObjectArray:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
 23  0x000000011384880f -[PBXPListArchiver _encodeObjectArray:forKey:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
 24  0x0000000113848c0c -[PBXPListArchiver encodeObjectArray:forKey:] (in DevToolsCore)
 25  0x00000001138168e0 -[PBXArchivingBinding writeValueForObject:toPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 26  0x00000001138151ff -[PBXObject _archiveValuesForArchiveMask:toPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 27  0x0000000113815b96 -[PBXObject writeToPListArchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 28  0x0000000113844d57 -[PBXPListArchiver _archiveObject:asWeakReference:] (in DevToolsCore)
 29  0x0000000113845d58 -[PBXPListArchiver initWithRootObject:delegate:role:] (in DevToolsCore)
 30  0x000000011384614d -[PBXPListArchiver initWithRootObject:delegate:] (in DevToolsCore)
 31  0x000000011381e732 -[PBXProject writeToFile:projectFile:userFile:outResultNotification:] (in DevToolsCore)
 32  0x000000011381f030 -[PBXProject _writeToFileSystemProjectFile:userFile:checkNeedsRevert:] (in DevToolsCore)
 33  0x000000011381f14e -[PBXProject writeToFileSystemProjectFile:userFile:checkNeedsRevert:] (in DevToolsCore)
 34  0x0000000113a2278d -[Xcode3Project writeToFilePath:forceWrite:error:] (in DevToolsCore)
 35  0x000000010de12ce5 -[IDEContainer _saveContainerForAction:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 36  0x00007fff8a8cf094 __NSFireTimer (in Foundation)
 37  0x00007fff84ba1724 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 38  0x00007fff84ba125f __CFRunLoopDoTimer (in CoreFoundation)
 39  0x00007fff84c1276a __CFRunLoopDoTimers (in CoreFoundation)
 40  0x00007fff84b5caa5 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 41  0x00007fff84b5c275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 42  0x00007fff891e0f0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 43  0x00007fff891e0b85 ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 44  0x00007fff891e0abc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 45  0x00007fff8c0ea28e _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 46  0x00007fff8c0e98db -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 47  0x00007fff8c0dd9cc -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 48  0x00007fff8c0c8803 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 49  0x00007fff89ee05fd start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a344866 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc335c pthread_kill + 92
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff87100bba abort + 125
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010e60b7af +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:reason:] + 775
4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010e60c00e -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] + 1117
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d38f7a5 _DVTAssertionHandler + 421
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d38fad4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 322
7   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001138f0f9c -[PBXContainerItemProxy _containerPortal] + 410
8   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113816694 -[PBXArchivingBinding writeValueForObject:toPListArchiver:] + 85
9   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001138151ff -[PBXObject _archiveValuesForArchiveMask:toPListArchiver:] + 389
10  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113815b96 -[PBXObject writeToPListArchiver:] + 75
11  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113844d57 -[PBXPListArchiver _archiveObject:asWeakReference:] + 716
12  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113847af8 -[PBXPListArchiver _encodeObject:forKey:asWeakReference:] + 263
13  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113847e12 -[PBXPListArchiver encodeObject:forKey:] + 53
14  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001138168e0 -[PBXArchivingBinding writeValueForObject:toPListArchiver:] + 673
15  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001138151ff -[PBXObject _archiveValuesForArchiveMask:toPListArchiver:] + 389
16  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113815b96 -[PBXObject writeToPListArchiver:] + 75
17  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011388aa1a -[PBXTargetDependency writeToPListArchiver:] + 81
18  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113844d57 -[PBXPListArchiver _archiveObject:asWeakReference:] + 716
19  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113848093 -[PBXPListArchiver _createPListArrayForObjectArray:asWeakReference:] + 547
20  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011384880f -[PBXPListArchiver _encodeObjectArray:forKey:asWeakReference:] + 278
21  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113848c0c -[PBXPListArchiver encodeObjectArray:forKey:] + 53
22  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001138168e0 -[PBXArchivingBinding writeValueForObject:toPListArchiver:] + 673
23  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001138151ff -[PBXObject _archiveValuesForArchiveMask:toPListArchiver:] + 389
24  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113815b96 -[PBXObject writeToPListArchiver:] + 75
25  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113844d57 -[PBXPListArchiver _archiveObject:asWeakReference:] + 716
26  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113848093 -[PBXPListArchiver _createPListArrayForObjectArray:asWeakReference:] + 547
27  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011384880f -[PBXPListArchiver _encodeObjectArray:forKey:asWeakReference:] + 278
28  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113848c0c -[PBXPListArchiver encodeObjectArray:forKey:] + 53
29  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001138168e0 -[PBXArchivingBinding writeValueForObject:toPListArchiver:] + 673
30  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001138151ff -[PBXObject _archiveValuesForArchiveMask:toPListArchiver:] + 389
31  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113815b96 -[PBXObject writeToPListArchiver:] + 75
32  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113844d57 -[PBXPListArchiver _archiveObject:asWeakReference:] + 716
33  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113845d58 -[PBXPListArchiver initWithRootObject:delegate:role:] + 882
34  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011384614d -[PBXPListArchiver initWithRootObject:delegate:] + 53
35  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011381e732 -[PBXProject writeToFile:projectFile:userFile:outResultNotification:] + 1040
36  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011381f030 -[PBXProject _writeToFileSystemProjectFile:userFile:checkNeedsRevert:] + 164
37  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011381f14e -[PBXProject writeToFileSystemProjectFile:userFile:checkNeedsRevert:] + 17
38  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113a2278d -[Xcode3Project writeToFilePath:forceWrite:error:] + 150
39  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010de12ce5 -[IDEContainer _saveContainerForAction:error:] + 864
40  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8a8cf094 __NSFireTimer + 96
41  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84ba1724 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
42  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84ba125f __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1151
43  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84c1276a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 298
44  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84b5caa5 __CFRunLoopRun + 1525
45  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84b5c275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
46  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff891e0f0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
47  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff891e0b85 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 173
48  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff891e0abc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
49  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8c0ea28e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
50  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8c0e98db -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
51  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8c0dd9cc -[NSApplication run] + 553
52  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8c0c8803 NSApplicationMain + 940
53  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff89ee05fd start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a345662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8669a43d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8669a152 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.low-priority
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a340a56 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8669ca15 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 206
2   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010dda6de9 -[IDEIndex gatherProductHeadersForIndexable:] + 258
3   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010dda692a +[IDEIndexingEngine runLoadJob:] + 131
4   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010ddd4003 -[IDEIndexingJob run] + 159
5   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010df95d10 __40-[IDEIndexingJobScheduler _scheduleJobs]_block_invoke + 33
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8669b1d7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff866982ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8669a09e _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8669b193 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc3ef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc6fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a340a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a33fd18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84b5d315 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84b5c939 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84b5c275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8a8d1907 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 348
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8a8d170b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc2899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc272a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc6fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a340a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a33fd18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84b5d315 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84b5c939 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84b5c275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x000000011762581a -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 164
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8a8d170b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc2899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc272a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc6fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a3449aa __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84ba8d43 __CFSocketManager + 867
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc2899 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc272a _pthread_start + 137
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc6fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a344716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc4c77 _pthread_cond_wait + 787
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff88ddf464 CVDisplayLink::waitUntil(unsigned long long) + 244
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff88dde998 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 496
4   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff88dde78f startIOThread(void*) + 147
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc2899 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc272a _pthread_start + 137
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc6fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a340a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a33fd18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84b5d315 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84b5c939 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84b5c275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8c28a1ce _NSEventThread + 144
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc2899 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc272a _pthread_start + 137
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc6fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a340a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a33fd18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84b5d315 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84b5c939 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84b5c275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8a8d3a7c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 253
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8a9bc70a -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x0000000118f0096b -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 132
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8a8d170b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc2899 _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc272a _pthread_start + 137
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc6fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a344e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc3f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc6fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.low-priority
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a340a56 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8669ca15 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 206
2   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d3cd1db DVTSyncPerformBlock + 274
3   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010dda3199 +[IDEIndex syncPerformBlockOnMainThread:] + 75
4   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010dda70ef -[IDEIndexableMainThreadProxy productHeadersInWorkspace:withCompletionBlock:] + 161
5   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010dda6dda -[IDEIndex gatherProductHeadersForIndexable:] + 243
6   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010dda692a +[IDEIndexingEngine runLoadJob:] + 131
7   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010ddd4003 -[IDEIndexingJob run] + 159
8   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010df95d10 __40-[IDEIndexingJobScheduler _scheduleJobs]_block_invoke + 33
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8669b1d7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff866982ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8669a09e _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8669b193 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc3ef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc6fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a344e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc3f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc6fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a344e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc3f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc6fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a340a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a33fd18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84b5d315 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84b5c939 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84b5c275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84c119d1 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff914037e3 SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 355
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc2899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc272a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc6fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a344a3a __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8711fe60 nanosleep + 200
2   com.apple.CoreSymbolication     0x00007fff87d6f681 0x7fff87d5c000 + 79489
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc2899 _pthread_body + 138
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc272a _pthread_start + 137
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86cc6fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff73fe8310  rcx: 0x00007fff52911cb8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000707  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff52911ce0  rsp: 0x00007fff52911cb8
   r8: 0x00007fff88a4d2ec   r9: 0x0000000000000081  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fff52911df8  r13: 0x000000010ecdd4e8  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x00007fb1eee3cb80
  rip: 0x00007fff8a344866  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x0000000111e9f000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was having the same issue and managed to solve it by modifying some offending lines in the project file via a text editor.

The main thing that led me to the solution of this problem was the error message from the report;

> Tried to access the containerPortal of an orphaned container item proxy. A common cause of this is corrupt project files which illegally reuse the same target dependency instance for multiple targets.

To fix this problem just follow my instructions below but ensure that xcode is closed before continuing.

Firstly, open the project container (go to finder, and do 'show package contents' on the xcodeproj file).

At this point based on some advice from another thread I cleared out all of the workspace settings and left nothing except the "pbxproj" file to be on a blank slate (I am not 100% sure if that was necessary, but it didn't hurt since the only things you lose are breakpoint locations, windows and tab locations, etc.).

Next, open the pbxproj file in a text editor and look for the word 'dependency'. This should lead you to a part of the file that says something like:

```
 /* Begin PBXNativeTarget section */
```

Below that you should see a section with all your targets listed. In my case I had my MainProject and my MainProject-cal targets, where I was trying to delete the MainProject-cal. In the error message it notes the use of the same dependency in multiple targets being a problem so I looked through. Here's what it looked like for me before I made any changes:

```
    /* Begin PBXNativeTarget section */
    xxxx /* MainProject */ = {
    ...
    dependencies = (
        A /* PBXTargetDependency */,
        B /* PBXTargetDependency */,
        C /* PBXTargetDependency */,
    );
    ...
    xxxx /* MainProject-cal */ = {
    ...
    dependencies = (
        D /* PBXTargetDependency */,
        B /* PBXTargetDependency */,
        F /* PBXTargetDependency */,
    );
    ...
    /* End PBXNativeTarget section */
```

(I simplified the hex into x's or single characters, and stripped out some extra stuff for readability)

So if you look based on my above excerpt you'll notice that the dependency 'B' appears both in the MainProject and MainProject-cal. In the dependencies of MainProject-cal I simply removed the offending line (e.g. cut out the line labelled 'B'), saved the file, and started  Xcode again. At that point, when I tried to remove the target everything worked fine and Xcode didn't crash. Problem solved! Hope that helps - I've been wrestling with this issue for weeks.

Comment: This works for me: the problem seems to be the target dependency referred to the same _address_ as the first main one. I manually removed the dependencies and manually add it back through Xcode. It allows to include the dependency but create a new reference to it under _dependencies_.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by manually editing the `project.pbxproj` too, but in my case there was nothing wrong with my dependencies.

After hunting around for a while trying to figure out the exact format of the file I settled with finding all references to the offending library and deleting them. Any lines which referenced it, and any blocks that references were removed.

I then opened Xcode and re-added the library and everything was fine again.